# Wordpress - 404 Page Perma link when is in "Post name"

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Recently i made and move a wordpress page to another server.
I flush the links and they work fine, but only if i use "Plain". Any other permalink option result in a 404 even if i click it on edit mode.

I try to use `flush_rewrite_rules( false );` on function.php inside the template and my htacces is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Did i miss something?

Thank you.

Comment: Aditional info: On the original server, that wordpress was placed on www.web-name.cl/clientes/wordpress and there all the permalinks works fine as "post name"